# Google Maps zoom level on mobile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made a google maps with the API. The map is working as it should, but I am not satisfied with the zoom level on mobile devices. I would like to zoom more out, but only on mobile.

Is it possible to change the zoom only on mobile?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var center = {lat: 56.463415, lng: 9.495170};
    var locations = [

      ['Headline', 'Headline<br>Address<br><a href="#" target="_blank">Show direction</a>', 1.686340, 15.998270],

    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: center
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    var marker, count;
    for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][2], locations[count][3]),
        map: map,
        title: locations[count][0]
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, count) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[count][1]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, count));
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get the display width by (window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio) and similarly the height (window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio).

Then you could e.g. check the max resolution on which your map becomes too small using dev tools in your browser.

At the end change the zoom property of that condition. For example:

```
var screenWidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
var screenHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
if (screenWidth < 600 && typeof map !== "undefined")
{
    map.setZoom(10);
}
```

Other way to detect mobile devices would be using http://www.modernizr.com/ library.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. I am just testing it out, but cannot make it work. Where would you set that in javascript? Maybe I am inserting the code incorrect?

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried and explain what doesn't work. Did you try to debug? Also the code posted above was partially wrong before I edited it. Check again.

Comment: MK_DK, You can paste the code at the end of your <script> snippet. It just necessary to place it where the google.maps.Map object already existis.